# Prism: Declare some Views that require some service to be working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I've a WPF application that display a server.

I've one region with basically two possible view, one is a welcome screen, the other one is the running instance informations

Currently the process is the following:

1. Launch the application
2. The application display the welcome screen and some option to load one of the configuration file
3. Select the server configuration file to open
4. The server initialize according to this configuration
5. Once the server is initialized, I ask the application to "Navigate" to the other view.

The issue is that Prism seems to initialize the ViewModel of my "InstanceInformation" view as soon as I register it:

`m_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionsNames.MAIN_TAB_REGION, typeof(StatusView));`

This is way to early because this ViewModel require some services that are not yet initialized(because they don't even know which server we have selected).

Is there a way to instantiate the ViewModel of my navigated View only when we navigate to it?

Answer (score 0):

You only use RegisterViewWithRegion when you want to instantly navigate to that view.  Don't use this unless you want your view to be shown in the region as soon as the region is created.  Otherwise use either IRegion.Add, or RequestNavigate.

Comment: I was using RequestNavigate, but this was displaying System.Object and not my control. So I was thinking it was required to navigate before navigating. how the URI should be generated based on my `StatusView` View that I want to display? Is it the full namespace? Some relative path? Just the name?

Comment: That is because you need to register your views for navigation first.  Otherwise it will show System.Object

Comment: And it's not the "RegisterViewWithRegion" method that does the job?

Comment: No, registerViewWithRegion is using view discovery to create and inject the view when the region has been created.  It is not called RegisterViewForNavigation, which is another extension method off of the Container.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to instantiate the ViewModel of my navigated View only when we navigate to it?

The view model will be created the first time you navigate to the view (by calling `RegionManager.RequestNavigate("nameOfTheView")`), *unless* you implemenmt `IRegionMemberLifetime` and return `false` from `KeepAlive`, in which case the view and its view model will be recreated each time they're navigated to.

To make navigation work, you have to make the view known as navigation target using `Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<TypeOfTheView>("nameOfTheView")`... if `"nameOfTheView"` happens to be `nameof(TypeOfTheView)`, you can omit the parameter as that's the default.

Side note: you can pass parameters with the navigation which are passed to `OnNavigatedTo` if you implement `INavigationAware`, independent of whether you're reusing the view/view model or recreating them.